# how to execute forcedeth at startup?

Tags: networking, 13.04

I'm trying to add the line

```
exec rmmod forcedeth
```

in the file

```
/etc/init/module-init-tools.conf
```

and then add the line

```
modprobe forcedeth msi=0 msix=0
```

to `/etc/rc.local`

but when I try the first command it says
not such file or directory, I'm trying to do all this because im trying to enable networking at startup because there is a bug with the drivers for my motherboard
my system specs are:

- board: N68C-GS FX
- processor: AMD FX eight core processor 3.6 Ghz

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04

can please someone help me?

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message?

Comment: Can you please post the link to the bug report?

Comment: I think you mean `rmmod`, not `rommod`

Comment: @Braiam, [#1003297](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1003297), [#1264509](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1264509).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you'll still need an answer for this, but just in case: module-init-tools has been replaced by kmod, so the first addition (`exec rmmod forcedeth`) should now be made to `/etc/init/kmod.conf` instead.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this very same problem, and spent a lot of time struggling to figure it out.

The individual at http://linuxconfig.org/nvidia-mcp55-forcedeth-module-not-working-with-linux came up with a solution that worked for me

```
echo options forcedeth msi=0 msix=0 >>/etc/modprobe.d/options.conf
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```